# Extend exception with new message

Tags: c#, excel

```
[Serializable]
public class CommonsDbException : Exception
{    
    public CommonsDbException()
    {
    }

    public CommonsDbException(string message, object[] args)
    {
        base.message = string.Format(message, args);
    }

    public CommonsDbException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected CommonsDbException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

but

```
public CommonsDbException(string message, object[] args)
{
    base.message = string.Format(message, args);
}
```

is not valid, I can not set Message on `base.Message`.

I want to create new message, what can I do. Message on father has no setter.

Comment: @BlackICE That is wrong. Constructors are not inherited. (If zero instance constructors are given, the compiler makes a default instance constructor for you, but that is another story.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to chain the constructor:

```
public CommonsDbException(string message, object[] args) : base(string.Format(message, args))
{

}
```

This calls the `Exception(string message)` constructor in the ancestor.

There's an article [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) on constructors that you should read.

Comment: I think it would be useful to add `params` to the final parameter (although not a part of his question).

Answer (score 0):

Exception has an [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ca3hhw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts a message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
public CommonsDbException(string message, object[] args) : base(string.Format(message, args), null)
{
}
```